# Spotipy (Spotify's Web API Python wrapper) examples failing

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, spotify, spotipy

I cloned and installed Paul Lamere's [Python wrapper for the Spotify Web API](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy) via `python setup.py install` but I can't seem to run some of the examples correctly.

Specifically, when I try to run [`user_playlists_contents.py`](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/user_playlists_contents.py) or [`user_starred_playlist.py`](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/user_starred_playlist.py), a browser is launched and I'm directed to the Spotify login page. After logging in, I get a Spotify error within the browser that only says: "Oops! Something went wrong." The script asks for the URL I was redirected to, but entering in both the URL of the login page and the URL of the error page (obviously) trigger an error within the Terminal: `spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request`

At first I was using a Facebook-connected Spotify account and logging in to Spotify through Facebook when prompted, so I thought that might be an issue. However even after creating a new email-only Spotify account and running the scripts on this new email-only username I got the same results.

I also tried registering a new App in my Spotify developer account and using its `CLIENT_ID`, `CLIENT_SECRET`, and `REDIRECT_URI` in the `examples/util.py` but this didn't seem to do anything. It seems unlikely anyways that modifying `examples/util.py` is necessary.

Thinking this might be a browser issue I also reset my browser (Chrome) and after that didn't work I tried switching Safari to the default browser but that also did nothing.

Both these scripts depend on `prompt_for_user_token()` which is defined in [`examples/util.py`](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/util.py), and seems to be where things are going wrong.

What am I doing wrong? Have I missed something painfully obvious? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should report this as an issue in its GitHub project, instead of using StackOverflow. That will notify the project's maintainers and would be able to help you out better.

Comment: @JMPerez I could do that. I tried StackOverflow first though because I thought this was something I was doing wrong, not a bug with the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`prompt_for_user_token` method looks as below:

```
def prompt_for_user_token(username, scope=None):
    ''' prompts the user to login if necessary and returns
        the user token suitable for use with the spotipy.Spotify 
        constructor
    '''

    client_id = os.getenv('CLIENT_ID', 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID')
    client_secret = os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET', 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET')
    redirect_uri = os.getenv('REDIRECT_URI', 'YOUR_REDIRECT_URI')
    .
    .
```

which requires you to set CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET and REDIRECT_URI environment variables before executing the example. You get these values by creating an app at [My Applications](https://developer.spotify.com/my-applications/#!/applications) section of [Spotify Developer Site](https://developer.spotify.com/)

In Unix, you can set environment variables in the command line as follows:

```
export CLIENT_ID={yourclient}
export CLIENT_SECRET={yoursecret}
export REDIRECT_URI={your redirect uri}
```

Then you need to copy and paste the full url you were redirected to on browser to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and found at least a work around solution. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444733/setting-spotify-credentials-using-spotipy/33445231#33445231). I got this to work by passing the `client_id`, `client_secret`, `redirect_uri` as agruments in `util.prompt_for_user_token`. I had to copy and paste the *entire* URL including code. I did not mess with `util.py` at all.

Comment: Consider incorporating the key elements of the content to which you have linked so your answer stands on its own.